# JsonObject jar file

Tags: java, json, jar

I imported the following imports to my code, however I still get an error for

```
JsonObject obj = new JsonParser().parse(input).getAsJsonObject();
```

"JsonObject cannot be resolved for a type."

```
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;
import org.json.JSONArray.*;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject.*;
import org.json.JSONString;
```

Answer (score 4):

Its `JSONObject` not `JsonObject`.

Same goes for the parser, it's `JSONParser` not `JsonParser`.

```
JSON is always uppercase.
```